# Jquery select input that is within a TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Here is the HTML code that I copied/pasted using Firebug:

```
<div id="TBI">
<tr class="t-state-selected t-grid-edit-row">
    <td>8081</td>

    <td class="t-grid-edit-cell">
        <input id="ijn" class="text-box single-line valid" type="text" value=""  name="ijn"> 
    </td>
```

I'm able to access the 2nd cell of this table using the following:

```
$('#TBI tr.t-state-selected')[0].cells[1]
```

and all works well.

But, how can I get a jquery reference to the input that is contained within the TD?  Once I figure out how to get a selector for that text box, I can manipulate it as I wish.

Thanks ahead of time for help!

Answer (score 9):

Just try:

```
$("#TBI tr.t-state-selected input")
```

Or for the input inside the second td:

```
$("#TBI tr.t-state-selected:nth-child(1) input");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMEue/)

Comment: In my case many of the TDs in a row have input elements.  I want the input that is from the 2nd td.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#TBI tr.t-state-selected td input')
```

Comment: FYI the state class is `t-state-selected` not `td-state-selected` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=text]", "div#TBI tr.t-state-selected td");
```